# conditional statement in an array

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to add conditional statement in author. something like if the author is an admin set this to null. is this possible?

```
$args = apply_filters( 'job_manager_get_dashboard_jobs_args', array(
    'post_type'           => 'job_listing',
    'post_status'         => array( 'publish', 'expired', 'pending' ),
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page'      => $posts_per_page,
    'offset'              => ( max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ) - 1 ) * $posts_per_page,
    'orderby'             => 'date',
    'order'               => 'desc',
    'author'              => get_current_user_id()
));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that `get_current_user_id()` is getting an id for author.

**Change your code from this:**

`'author'              => get_current_user_id()`

**With this:**

`'author'              => ((get_current_user_id() == 'admin') ? NULL : get_current_user_id())`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this sample code.

```
<?php 
    $array = array('test' => testFunction());

    function testFunction()
    {
        // do your condition here
        // return 'a';
    }

    print_r($array);
?>
```